# Grails g:if tag test request URI

Tags: grails, httprequest, gsp

I am somewhat new to Grails and not sure how to accomplish this. I am dealing with a navigation list in my gsp file. What I am trying to do is test whether the request URI starts with a given string and if so, set the list item to active. The way I had seen to do this in the past was like this:

```
<li
    <g:if test="${request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/packageName/domainController")}">
        class="active"
    </g:if>
>
<g:link controller="sectionHome" params="[section: section]" >
    Class Home
</g:link>
</li>
```

This model doesn't work. Not sure if there is a tag out of order, or if there is a new method I just can't find. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think you need to use the request.forwardURI ( http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html ). Try printing them both out --- I think grails mangles the requestURI to the dispatcher.

Comment: Tried this. For some reason, request.forwardURI() isn't recognized, which is odd considering it's in the documentation. I tried it both in the gsp file and the controller.

Comment: it is a property, so either request.forwardURI or request.getForwardURI()

Comment: It isn't being recognized either way

Comment: can you do a println in the controller? It should be there. Not sure if it is available in the gsp.

Comment: So that does work, but its not working in the gsp file :/

Comment: Ya. Well, you can always pass it. http://grails.org/plugin/navigation and platform core will give you the functionality you want. We've usually just relied on the viewName and controllerName in the gsps to highlight the path.

Answer (score 0):

You have in your gsp to `${controllerName}` and `${actionName}` so you can do something like:

```
<li
    <g:if test="${controllerName == 'MyController'}">
        class="active"
    </g:if>
>
```

Hope that helps!